# Please help me with the following code in pinescript

Tags: pine-script

How to I get the following code to work?

//@version=3

```
strategy("My Strategy", overlay=true)

longCondition = crossover(ema(close, 13), vwap) and crossover(ADX, DIMinus) and crossover(MACD, MACDSignal)

if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long)

shortCondition = crossunder(ema(close, 13), vwap) and crossover(ADX, DIPLUS) and crossover(MACDSignal, MACD)
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Short Entry Id", strategy.short)
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Actually....I am not able to code it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what many of those variables are, but the code  below is my suggest based on names of the provided variables. They are similar to the output of Directional movement indicator and macd indicator values. Use this code as an example to build your own code.

```
//@version=3
strategy("My Strategy", overlay=true)
len = input(14, minval=1, title="DI Length")
lensig = input(14, title="ADX Smoothing", minval=1, maxval=50)

up = change(high)
down = -change(low)
DIPLUS = na(up) ? na : (up > down and up > 0 ? up : 0)
DIMinus = na(down) ? na : (down > up and down > 0 ? down : 0)
trur = rma(tr, len)
plus = fixnan(100 * rma(DIPLUS, len) / trur)
minus = fixnan(100 * rma(DIMinus, len) / trur)
sum = plus + minus
ADX = 100 * rma(abs(plus - minus) / (sum == 0 ? 1 : sum), lensig)

[MACD, MACDSignal, histLine] = macd(close, 12, 26, 9)


longCondition = crossover(ema(close, 13), vwap) and crossover(ADX, DIMinus) and crossover(MACD, MACDSignal)

if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long)

shortCondition = crossunder(ema(close, 13), vwap) and crossover(ADX, DIPLUS) and crossover(MACDSignal, MACD)
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Short Entry Id", strategy.short)
```

Comment: Thanks will try.

Comment: its not showing long and sell signals

Comment: Because the condition never happens to be true. Plot the values and you'll see that your conditions are always false 
`
plot(longCondition ? 1 : 0, color=red)
plot(shortCondition ? 1 : 0, color=blue)
`

Comment: True..... for longcondition I want crossover(ema(close, 13), vwap) and ADX greater than DIMinus and MACD greater than MACDSignal.   Shortcondition I want crossunder(ema(close, 13), vwap) and ADX greater than DIPlus and MACDSignal greater than MACD.  Could you please edit this for me.

Comment: What's the problem to do it by yourself? You already described all required statements, so you need only change crossover to sign `>`

Comment: Bro...I don't know programming

Comment: Can you please modify it to give me signals?  It would be of great help.

Comment: No way, man. Nobody will write code for you. You know what you want and you have all the tools for it. Logical and comparision operators are described here: https://www.tradingview.com/wiki/Operators#Comparison_Operators_.28.3C.2C_.3C.3D.2C_.21.3D.2C_.3D.3D.2C_.3E.2C_.3E.3D.29 Just put what you write by words in correct order and it'll work.